# Adding a generic 'contain_keys' method to a HashMap that works with &[&str] and &[String]

Tags: hashmap, rust, key

I would like to add a `contain_keys()` method to a `HashMap` to test whether it contains several keys.

I tested the following implementation:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait ContainKeys<K> {
    fn contains_keys<Q>(&self, keys: &[Q]) -> bool
        where K: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Sized + Hash + Eq + Ord;
}

impl<V> ContainKeys<String> for HashMap<String, V> {
    fn contains_keys<Q>(&self, some_keys: &[Q]) -> bool
        where String: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Sized + Hash + Eq + Ord
    {
        some_keys.iter().all(|ref key| self.contains_key(key))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, _> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("key 1".to_string(), "value 1");
    map.insert("key 2".to_string(), "value 2");

    println!("map = {:?}", map);

    assert_eq!(map.contains_keys(&["key 1".to_string(), "key 2".to_string()]),
               true);
    assert_eq!(map.contains_keys(&["key 1".to_string(), "key 3".to_string()]),
               false);
}
```

I had to increase to `?Sized` requirement from the original `contain_key()` method since I was passing a `&[Q]`.

It compiles and runs but I find it quite cumbersome to have to add all these `to_string()` to the keys.

Is there a better (ideally generic) implementation that could work using a syntax like the following:

```
fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<_, _> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("key 1", "value 1");
    map.insert("key 2", "value 2");

    println!("map = {:?}", map);

    assert_eq!(map.contains_keys(&["key 1", "key 2"]), true);
    assert_eq!(map.contains_keys(&["key 1", "key 3"]), false);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to say `HashMap<_, _>`; the compiler will infer the types based on what you insert. You can just say `let mut map = HashMap::new();`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for that @Shepmaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr, this is a generic solution which doesn't restrict you to `String`:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait ContainKeys<K: Hash + Eq> {
    fn contains_keys<Q: ?Sized>(&self, keys: &[&Q]) -> bool
        where K: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Hash + Eq + Ord;
}

impl<V, K: Hash + Eq> ContainKeys<K> for HashMap<K, V> {
    fn contains_keys<Q: ?Sized>(&self, some_keys: &[&Q]) -> bool
        where K: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Hash + Eq + Ord
    {
        some_keys.iter().all(|key| self.contains_key(key))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, _> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("key 1".to_string(), "value 1");
    map.insert("key 2".to_string(), "value 2");

    println!("map = {:?}", map);

    assert_eq!(map.contains_keys(&["key 1", "key 2"]), true);
    assert_eq!(map.contains_keys(&["key 1", "key 3"]), false);
}
```

In the documentation, both `K` and `Q` must implement `Hash + Eq`.

I also had to change the trait signature so `Q: &Sized` ... which means I had to say: `keys: &[&Q]` so every key is `Sized`.

Comment: thanks @tafia for the solution and indeed the addition of the contraints to K